# Electron - detect window blur event when launching the screen capture app on Mac

Tags: javascript, events, electron

I want to detect when the user releases the shift key. This can be done using the `blur` event on the window. However, if the user presses `shift+cmd+5` on Mac to launch the screen capture app, the window doesn't emit this event when the user releases the shift.

Is there another way to detect that event (in vanilla JS or Electron)?
Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue right now, have you find an event to listen to ?

Comment: @Apolo no, I couldn't find any simple solution